# Destruct a string from split to named object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I am investigating how create a named object in one go, using destruct

A search for [javascript destruct* split object](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+%2Bdestruct*+split+object+site%3Astackoverflow.com) did not reveal how to directly destruct a string into an object using split.

I do not mean reduce or map but pure destructing

```
const list = { ..... } = `......`.split(..)
```

or at least

```
const rowItem = { ..... } = `......`.split(..)
```

My initial version works, but there should be a neater way with less steps

The initial split on lines is fine. It is the filling of the list using destruct I am curious about

```js
const rows = `100|Description 1|a|
101|Description 2|a|
102|Description 3|b|`.split("\n")

let list = {}
rows.forEach(row => {
  const [ProductId, Description, subCat, ] = row.split("|")
  list[ProductId] = {"Description": Description, "subCat": subCat }
})

console.log(list)
```

Comment: What do you expect the destructuring of the array returned from split into an object to do?

Comment: You could use [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) for `Description` and `subCat`

Comment: You can make the construction of the list cleaner with `Object.fromEntries`, but I'm thinking that's not what you're looking for

Comment: @JonasHøgh I wanted to not have to first desctruct creating two objects and then parse into a 3rd object.

Comment: @adiga could I use them in the same line as the destruct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this with IIFE

```js
const rows = `100|Description 1|a|
101|Description 2|a|
102|Description 3|b|`.split("\n")

let list = {}
rows.forEach(row => {
  (([ProductId, Description, subCat]) => (list[ProductId] = {
    Description,
    subCat
  }))(row.split("|"))
})

console.log(list)
```

Comment: @mplungjan i thought you wanted to everything on same line, so i suggested this

Comment: Just the same statement ("in one go") :) I like the passing of the split as parameter

Comment: @mplungjan yeah "in one go" that's what made me think for approach :)

Comment: We can save a pair of brackets :) `rows.forEach(row => {
  (
    ([ProductId, Description, subCat]) => list[ProductId] = { Description, subCat }
  )(row.split("|"))
})`

Comment: I like yours the best for now. The destructuring you added is the `([ProductId, Description, subCat])` which I now remember I have seen

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [Object.fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) if it's available in your environment

```js
const rows = Object.fromEntries(`100|Description 1|a|
101|Description 2|a|
102|Description 3|b|`
  .split("\n")
  .map(row => row.split('|'))
  .map(([key, Description, subCat]) => [key, { Description, subCat }])
);

console.log(rows);
```

Comment: Hmm, the last .map is interesting

Comment: No need for `.map` followed by `.map` - just use the split string inside the first callback and return the array

Comment: @CertainPerformance Please show the syntax of what you meant?

Comment: @mplungjan `.map(row => {
    const [key, Description, subCat] = row.split('|');
    return [key, { Description, subCat }];
  })`, looks pretty similar to what you were doing originally

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, that is true - the thing I like here is the `[key, { Description, subCat }]`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the property to an existing object while destructuring.

```js
const row = { Description: 'Description 1', subCat: 'a' },
      o = { }; // existing object to be updated;

({ Description: o.Description, subCat: o.subCat } = row);

console.log(o)
```

In your case, you have dynamic `id` keys, nested property updates and you are destructuring an array instead of an object. It becomes complex, but it *is* possible to apply the above logic to your code <sub>(This is extremely hackish and purely academic. This should **never ever** be used in an actual code base)</sub>

```js
const str = "100|Description 1|a|",
      splits = str.split('|'),
      list = {};// existing object
      
({ 0: id, [-1]: list[id]= {}, 1: list[id].Description, 2: list[id].subCat } = splits)

console.log(list)
```

This destructures the array like an object. It gets the property with key `0` and sets it to the `id` variable. Then destructure the `-1` property. This is non-existent, so the [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variables_names_and_providing_default_values) is used and `list[id] = {}` is set.

This is how the transpiled code looks like:

```js
var _str$split = str.split('|');

id = _str$split[0];
list[id] = _str$split[-1] === undefined ? {} : _str$split[-1];
list[id].Description = _str$split[1];
list[id].subCat = _str$split[2];
console.log(list);
```

Applying this to your original snippet:

```js
const rows = `100|Description 1|a|
101|Description 2|a|
102|Description 3|b|`

let list = {},
    id;

rows.split("\n")
  .forEach(str => ({
    0: id,
    [-1]: list[id] = {}, 
    1: list[id].Description,
    2: list[id].subCat
  } = str.split('|'))
)

console.log(list)
```

---

Another option is to use [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) and `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
const str = `100|Description 1|a|
101|Description 2|a|
102|Description 3|b|`;

const regex = /(\d+)\|([^|]+)\|(\w+)/g;
    
const output = Object.fromEntries(
    Array.from(
      str.matchAll(regex), ([, id, Description, subCat]) => [id, { Description, subCat }]
    )
)

console.log(output)
```

`matchAll` is still in [Draft stage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Specifications) but it is implemented except by IE and Safari. You can easily [polyfill it](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-matchall). It is basically looping through [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) results

Comment: how about using callback of `Array.from` instead , i.e `Array.from(str.matchAll(regex),(([, id, Description, subCat]) => [id, { Description, subCat }]))
    )`

Comment: Neater now :) Thanks

Comment: @mplungjan I have updated the answer. It **is** possible to do that in the same line. But, it is completely unreadble because of the nested property assignment

Comment: I have to admit I really like the first one. It is a nasty use of side effects but still when formatted makes sense - It actually answers my question as posed but I would be afraid to use it in real life ;)

Comment: @ `-1` is used to create a nested object with newly created `id` as key. Since `-1` doesn't exist, [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variables_names_and_providing_default_values) will be used